# How to force a node inside tiny mce?

Tags: tinymce

I'm using tiny mce for my project and want to validate the node inside the tiny mce. On click of a text element, let's say a paragraph with some id, I load editor for the element. But, sometimes if user replaces the whole content, the node and its HTML is lost. I want to retain this node and only the content is removed. The node can be a paragraph or heading or ul or ol.

**EDIT :**
I'm providing dummy text such as "Lorem epsum .....". User will be removing this dummy text and add his content.

**EDIT2**
I want to allow the user to change the content only and the surrounding HTML and styles should remain intact.

How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: at what moment does the user replace the whole content in this case?

Comment: so what you want is what? option1: the dummy text (with surrounding paragraph) stays in the editor, the user changes does not get applied. option2: the user changes are applied, but the deleted paragraph will stay in the editor (above or bellow the users edited content). option3: you want to prohibit the user from touching your paragraph at all (no styling, no editing, nothing)? Your question text states that "I want to retain this node and only the content is removed". This sounds like all text content may be gone, but the empty node should stay there(?).

Comment: or should it be filled with the user changes? in that case it will be difficult to find out what the user intended to do, because he removed the whole content first.

Answer (score 0):

This would check if node content is in editor, and if not will add it at the bottom.

```
var nodecontent;
if (!tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent().match(/nodecontent/) {
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()+nodecontent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new button in tinymce which gives you a pop-up asking for the ID or the title of a node. This button then puts a small piece of "code" in the tinymce textfield.

for example:  ((id:10))

When loading a node, you can search if the current node has that "code" in it by a regular expression. If it has, load the content from the node with that ID from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it will be very tricky to keep the surrounding html while the user is able to delete html elements in the editor. You would need to intercept each attempt where a user could delete your surrounding html (Copy/paste, delete, backspace, usage of the code-plugin, and so on...) and then handle it case for case.

**Suggestion:**

In case the surrounding html will never change you could give the user total control over the editor content through adding the surrounding html after the user submits/saves the editor content. To keep the style even without the surrounding html it might be sufficient to create a css class and apply it to the body element of the editors iframe. The body element is not deletable. I do not know if this is acceptable in your use-case (let us know).